# Python Applying map function to sub list

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I have an array holding another object items :

```
myarray=[]
myarray.append((1,2,3))
myarray.append((4,5,6))
```

how can I apply a map function to the last 2 columns of the list 
somethign like

```
def inc(x):
  return x+1
```

then

```
myarray map (inc) # only to the last 2 columns (2,3) and (5,6)
```

in short I want to transform the data structure from

```
((1,2,3))
((4,5,6))
```

to

```
((1,3,4))
((4,6,7))
```

thanks

EDIT:
just so others can benfit from this I wrote to functions based on @alef response

```
def format_sub_list(_list,i):
  return [[y if i < len(x)-i else inc(y)
  for i, y in enumerate(x)]
  for x in _list]
```

or

```
def format_sub_list2(_list,sublist):
  return [[y if i in (sublist) else inc(y)
  for i, y in enumerate(x)]
  for x in _list]
```

Comment: Shall the result be just the return values of the `inc` or shall it also contain the values which have not been given to `inc`?

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific, I just did an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[y if i < len(x)-2 else inc(y)
  for i, y in enumerate(x)]
  for x in my_array]
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I modified it so that r=[[y if i in (1,4) else inc(y)
  for i, y in enumerate(x)]
  for x in myarray]  , this way it will be more flexiable in terms of excepting various conditions

Answer (score 1):

```
l[:-2] + tuple(map(inc, l[-2:]))
```

Comment: Yeah, but I guessed that the number `2` would not be constant.  Also the number of columns might be variable.  I feel your answer is based on assuming too much.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree with Alfe, this is somewhat hard coded.

Comment: I agree , it is more flexible

Comment: The adding needs to be done for each tuple (being an element of the array).